# set_gamma missing in python3

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have some legacy code from Python2.7 that created figures.  Part of the process involved setting gamma in the colorbar (I honestly don't know what the set_gamma function does, but it is there).  However, this no longer works in Python3.x.  Example below

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

fig = pl.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(111)

plt = ax0.imshow(np.random.randint(0, 100, (100, 100))
bound = list(np.arange(0, 100, 5))
cbar = fig.colorbar(plt, boundaries=bound, values=bound[:-1])

# here is the problem line; works in 2.7, not in 3.x
cbar.cmap.set_gamma(0.9)
```

Two questions:

1. what does set_gamma do?
2. can I use set_gamma (or an equivalent) in 3.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the python version. It's that you use two different matplotlib versions. One of them has a `LinearSegmentedColormap` as default, the other has a `ListedColormap` as default. `set_gamma` only makes sense for `LinearSegmentedColormap`s.

You may find out which colormaps are `LinearSegmentedColormap` via this code:

```
from matplotlib.cm import cmap_d

for name, cmap in cmap_d.items():
    print(name, type(cmap))
```

The old default `"jet"` colormap *is* such a `LinearSegmentedColormap`, hence in your code add the colormap to use explicitely,

```
im = ax.imshow(..., cmap="jet")
```

---

As to what `gamma` is: It's a correction to the colormap's brightness and contrast, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction. Since 0.9 is pretty close to 1, I cannot actually make out a difference between using the gamma correction in this case vs. not using it. So if in doubt and if the application does not require a special color profile, I would say just leave it out entirely.

Comment: That's a great answer and it makes sense that this is a colormap issue as opposed to a version issue.  Also, thanks for the wikipedia link to explain gamma correction.  Many thanks.